# Check Geopoint within geoFence and Distance in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, google-maps, geolocation

I am new to Java. I have created a geofence with circle shape. I know the center(Latitude,longitude) point and radius(in meter). I want to check whether a geo point(i.e. latitude, longitude) is within this fence, and if it is true I want to find distance between that geopoint to the center point. How can I do this in java. In mysql there is one query for doing this

```
 SELECT tripid,create_time, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(8.475316) ) * cos(    
radians(lattitude ) ) * cos(
radians( longitude ) - radians(76.962528) ) + sin( radians(8.475316) ) * sin(  
 radians( lattitude ) ) ) ) AS
 distance
FROM pack_history where speed<5 and tripid=685  HAVING distance < 0.10 ORDER BY       
create_time desc LIMIT 0 ,100;
```

How can i do this similar functionality in Java??
[image]

Comment: take a look at [java.lang.Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class. For all the mathematical calculations

Answer (score 5):

You simply need a method that calculates the distance between two lat/ lon coordinates.
(search here on SO or internet, this is easy to find).
if the distance is < r then the point is inside the circle.

Answer (score 0):

> This function is to calculate the **Distance** between two lat/lon coordinates

```
private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, char unit) {
  double theta = lon1 - lon2;
  double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
  dist = Math.acos(dist);
  dist = rad2deg(dist);
  dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  if (unit.equals("K")) {
    dist = dist * 1.609344;
  } else if (unit.equals("N")) {
  dist = dist * 0.8684;
  }
  return (dist);    
}
```

> This function converts decimal degrees to radians

```
private double deg2rad(double deg) {
  return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
}
```

> This function converts radians to decimal degrees

```
private double rad2deg(double rad) {
  return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
}
```

> If you want in **Miles** pass **M** as unit

```
system.println(distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") + " Miles\n");
```

> If you want in **Kilometers** pass **K** as unit

```
system.println(distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "K") + " Kilometers\n");
```

> If you want in **Nautical Miles** pass **N** as unit

```
system.println(distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "N") + " Nautical Miles\n");
```